# Can't browser cache images served by Cloud Front in React App

Tags: reactjs, amazon-cloudfront

I deployed a Lambda function that resizes images to Amazon CloudFront with using this template.
https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/serverless-image-handler/

Everything works fine, except i can't cache images in browser. Everytime image requested it gets from Lambda Function's Cloud Front Distribution.

How can browser cache images served by Cloud Front in React App ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added Cache-Control max-age meta information to Lambda Function response. 
And this solved my problem.